# PyOpenSSL throws error loading a certificate

Tags: python, openssl, pyopenssl

I have the following code

```
key = OpenSSL.crypto.PKey()
key.generate_key(OpenSSL.crypto.TYPE_RSA, 1024)
cert = OpenSSL.crypto.X509()
cert.set_pubkey(key)
cert.sign(key, 'sha1')
public_key =  OpenSSL.crypto.dump_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, cert)
cert2 = OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, public_key)
```

the last line throws the following error, that is strange because nowhere I'm uding ASN1

```
OpenSSL.crypto.Error: [('asn1 encoding routines', 'ASN1_get_object', 'too long'), ('asn1 encoding routines', 'ASN1_CHECK_TLEN', 'bad object header'), ('asn1 encoding routines', 'ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I', 'nested asn1 error'), ('asn1 encoding routines', 'ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I', 'nested asn1 error'), ('asn1 encoding routines', 'ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I', 'nested asn1 error'), ('asn1 encoding routines', 'ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I', 'nested asn1 error'), ('PEM routines', 'PEM_ASN1_read_bio', 'ASN1 lib')]
```

this is the content of public_key

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIBVDCBvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADAAMAQfAB8AMAAwgZ8wDQYJKoZIhvcN
AQEBBQADgY0AMIGJAoGBALKnfGRn5ajhcUJTs4PfwBfmjkpaDNeeRJfg8PmFRVFC
nZZPJTQoqrEAWnpGSHP1KWwiRcA7iFOIGe5lOj+vficIxGcNNv6n/OxBKLEeFYkb
+GoLyALEFcBPToe0KSHIcRwZcx6wg0kvtBCzTn1rA195u/tiuZfhza7ho7Se9g+X
AgMBAAEwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQADgYEArhzT6wsfV5e2JetlZ7erOj0gkG046kow
B2wqmUvvQIxtZX+RYQBJvxlaaSJTSKjzjSafXIraemsPkkej9C9OudU54gfArvSK
UgSfkg4yABNUIWiSjEGdzFAoqmpPhKFXDoeW3SvqQdu+EZD/MF+AxmXufLADYGch
1Ga3c2SkOj8=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

What causes it?

Comment: X.509 certificates are encoded in ASN.1 DER (the DER-encoded value is occasionally wrapped in PEM encoding, which is base64 with begin/end lines), which is why you're getting an error from the ASN.1 parsing code. An "object too long" error usually means that you've given it invalid input, though, and it has read a garbled length field which extends past the end of the input.

Answer (score 4):

You're actually producing an invalid certificate with `dump_certificate`. Openssl should error out, or pyopenssl should check it, but either way - it's a bug.

This is just a guess, but likely it fails because of some required fields missing: serial number, validity, subject, issuer. Try setting those.

If you have time, report this snippet as a bug to pyopenssl too - you should never get bad PEM from it in the first place.

Comment: I was having the exact same problem, generating the exact same error.  This solution worked for me!

Comment: Same here, thank you for the solution. I was missing validity.